# How to Deal with JavaScript Closure when Using Async Code from a Separate Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, axios

I'm trying to create a cleanup function for my `useEffect` and update the variable `cancelRequest` that is being used by the code from my `getAllTweets()` function.

```js
let cancelRequest = false;

useEffect(() => {
    if (!url) {
        dispatch({ type: "IDLE" });
        return;
    }

    getAllTweets();

    return function cleanup() {
        cancelRequest = true;
    };
}, [state.page]);

...

function getAllTweets() {
    axiosConfig
        .get(`${url}?page=${state.page}`)
        .then((response) => {
            if (cancelRequest) {
                dispatch({ type: "IDLE" });
                return;
            } else if (state.page !== -1) {
                state.page === 1
                    ? dispatch({ type: "LOADED", payload: response.data.data })
                    : dispatch({
                            type: "LOADED",
                            payload: [...state.tweets, ...response.data.data],
                      });
            }

            ...
        })

        ...
}
```

But I think the variable wasn't being updated as I'm still getting the `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component` warning on my app when I'm trying to exit while it was fetching data.

Comment: I don't see any state setters in your code, you're only calling `dispatch` - is that from redux? If so, don't redux state changes have nothing to do with whether a particular component is mounted or not? Have any other state setters that might be getting called? (just thinking out loud)

Comment: I'm not using redux the dispatch is from my useReducer hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useReducer` performs the same sort of role as `useState` - it stores state but is said to be useful for handling complex state logic. But still, if you use `useReducer` in a component, and that component becomes unmounted, you shouldn't call dispatch again, because it corresponds to state *in that component only*. Even just doing

```
dispatch({ type: "IDLE" });
```

will produce a React warning.

But there's another potential issue. `cancelRequest` is a component-scoped variable, which means there will be a separate binding for that variable each render - so reassigning `cancelRequest` in only a single render may not be enough in case there's also an async action going on from a prior render. Use a ref instead, which is persistent across all renders.  The cleanup to change the ref should be in a separate `useEffect(.., [])` so that it'll run only when the component unmounts, rather than every time the page changes.

```
const cancelReqestRef = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
    // When unmounting, and only when unmounting, change the ref
    return () => cancelReqestRef.current = true;
}, []);
useEffect(() => {
    if (!url) {
        dispatch({ type: "IDLE" });
        return;
    }
    getAllTweets();
}, [state.page]);

...

function getAllTweets() {
    axiosConfig
        .get(`${url}?page=${state.page}`)
        .then((response) => {
            if (cancelReqestRef.current) {
                // DO NOT update state here with dispatch, just return
                return;
            } else if (state.page !== -1) {
                state.page === 1
                    ? dispatch({ type: "LOADED", payload: response.data.data })
                    : dispatch({
                            type: "LOADED",
                            payload: [...state.tweets, ...response.data.data],
                      });
            }

            ...
        })

        ...
}
```

Comment: "*Use a ref instead, which is persistent across all renders.*" - I don't think that is intended. When `state.page` changes, you want to load the current page and cancel *previous* loads, not prevent all loads.

Comment: Ah, good point, the cleanup there runs every time the dependency changes, not just on umount.